# Issue in IIS webadministration module running Get-Childitem

Tags: iis, powershell

I am having an odd issue.  I have one machine running IIS, PowerShell 3.0 with the webadministration module loaded.

I can get to IIS: so I know that the module is loading, but when I cd into /Sites and try to Get-ChildItem I get an error.  Likewise with Get-Website.

Here is the error.

```
format-default : Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

All I have seen online is that you need to be running 32 bit across the board (I am).  Any idea?

Comment: I don't know about 32 vs 64 bit, but what is your Execution Policy (you can check with `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and set it using `Set-ExecutionPolicy`)? If it is `Restricted` the WebAdministration module won't load successfully and you'd have seen an error message when loading the WebAdministration module. Try starting a new powershell windows, ensure the execution policy is `RemoteSigned` (I believe that's the strictest one possible) or looser and then import the webadministration module. Does that make any difference?

Comment: It was set to restricted, I have set it to unrestricted and still nothing.

Comment: I resolved this myself.  WAS was not installed on the machine, because it is being used only for FTP.  WAS is required by the webadministration module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out WAS was not installed on the server, and it is required by the webadministration module.